# Elegant way to select association elements whose values are not Null or empty list

Tags: associations

I'm relatively unfamiliar with associations. I wish to select association elements (i.e., keys *and* values) whose values are not `Null` or `{}` (i.e., an empty list). What's an elegant, efficient way to do this?

Consider an association `myAssociation`:

```
myAssociation = <|prefix -> "Dr.", firstName -> "Andrew", suffix -> Null,
   nickname -> "", aliases -> {}, streetAddress -> 1234, province -> Null,
   favoriteColors -> {"blue", "yellow"},"favoriteVegetables" -> {},
   "favoriteFruits" -> {"peaches", "plums"}|>;
```

I wish to return elements whose values are not `Null` or `{}`. I have found that [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) -- in tandem with `==`, `===`, or [`MemberQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html) -- can be used to select elements with values `Null` or `{}`:

```
Select[myAssociation, (# == {}) || (# == Null) &]
Select[myAssociation, (# === {}) || (# === Null) &]
Select[myAssociation, MemberQ[{Null, {}}, #] &]
```

> `<|suffix -> Null, aliases -> {}, province -> Null, "favoriteVegetables" -> {}|>`

> `<|suffix -> Null, aliases -> {}, province -> Null, "favoriteVegetables" -> {}|>`

> `<|suffix -> Null, aliases -> {}, province -> Null, "favoriteVegetables" -> {}|>`

So, to find elements without values of `Null` or `{}`, I need to simply invert the selection criteria:

```
Select[myAssociation, ! MemberQ[{Null, {}}, #] &]
```

> `<|prefix -> "Dr.", firstName -> "Andrew", nickname -> "", streetAddress -> 1234, favoriteColors -> {"blue", "yellow"}, "favoriteFruits" -> {"peaches", "plums"}|>`

Is there an easier, more elegant, more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `KeyValueMap`:

```
KeyValueMap[If[FreeQ[Null | {}][#2], #1 -> #2, Nothing] &, myAssociation]
```

Or a shorter version using `Select`:

```
Select[myAssociation, FreeQ[Null | {}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myAssociation =
  <|prefix -> "Dr.", firstName -> "Andrew", suffix -> Null, 
   nickname -> "", aliases -> {}, streetAddress -> 1234, 
   province -> Null, favoriteColors -> {"blue", "yellow"}, 
   "favoriteVegetables" -> {}, 
   "favoriteFruits" -> {"peaches", "plums"}|>;
```

**1.**

We use `Position` to get a list of the unwanted `Keys`

```
p = First /@ Position[myAssociation, Null | {}]
```

{Key[suffix], Key[aliases], Key[province], Key["favoriteVegetables"]}

and use it with `KeyDrop`

```
KeyDrop[p] @ myAssociation
```

<|prefix -> "Dr.", firstName -> "Andrew", nickname -> "",
streetAddress -> 1234, favoriteColors -> {"blue", "yellow"},
"favoriteFruits" -> {"peaches", "plums"}|>

**2.**

If we want to change `myAssociation` inline we can use `KeyDropFrom`

```
KeyDropFrom[myAssociation, p];

myAssociation
```

<|prefix -> "Dr.", firstName -> "Andrew", nickname -> "",
streetAddress -> 1234, favoriteColors -> {"blue", "yellow"},
"favoriteFruits" -> {"peaches", "plums"}|>

Answer (score 3):

```
DeleteCases[Null | {}] @ myAssociation
```

> ```
> <|prefix -> "Dr.",   
>   firstName -> "Andrew",   
>   nickname -> "",   
>   streetAddress -> 1234,   
>   favoriteColors -> {"blue", "yellow"},   
>   "favoriteFruits" -> {"peaches", "plums"}|>
> ```